# How Create multi select box to create tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Want have a multi select box to create tags,I used this code and download `select2.min.css` and `select2.min.js` from https://github.com/select2/select2 and copied in css and js file in project,
My code in html file is here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https: 
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="
        {{asset('css/select2.min.css')}}">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/select2.full.min.js')}}">
      </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/select2.min.js')}}">
   </script>

<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tags">tags:</label>
        <select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags" 
        multiple="multiple">
            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                <option value='{{$tag->id}}'>{{$tag->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
  <script>

  $('.select2-multi').select2();


</script>
```

But this Code didn't Work for me,How I Can fixed it?
Image of this code is here:[image]

Comment: Are you using Angular and jQuery? Your code appears to be using both.

Comment: No,How I can use this?

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: bootstrap javascript required and jquery is not defined in select2.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in your project as `$` will be undefined. Below is the sample:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tags">tags:</label>
    <select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags" multiple="multiple">
        <option value='tag1'>tag 1</option>
        <option value='tag2'>tag 2</option>
        <option value='tag3'>tag 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    $('.select2-multi').select2();
</script>
```

But it will always be a good practice to include your JS code on DOM ready like:

```
$(function(){
  $('.select2-multi').select2();
});
```