# How to do a tag labelling option with HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Actually i want to do a tag management module like **git lab tag management option in issues**

How can i do with  dynamic tags

[image]

sample Code

```
  <select class="form-control" id="label"  name="label">
    <option value="value" style="background-color:green" >Green</option>
 <option value="value" style="background-color:red" >red</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: On stack overflow it's expected that you attempt to do something before asking, and provide what you've tried

Comment: Best bet will be to get a plugin, [tag:select2] has an option for [tags](https://select2.org/placeholders#multi-select-placeholders)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Create multi select box to create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965937/how-create-multi-select-box-to-create-tags)

Comment: yes , but i want to colour  the tag dynamically like in the above image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div class="container">
     <select name="label[]" multiple="multiple" id="label-list">
            @foreach ($labels as $label)
               <option value="{{ $label->id }} class="{{$label->color}}" >{{ $label->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
        </select>
   </div>

 <script>
 $("#label-list").select2({
      width: "100%",
    templateSelection: function (data, container) {
        
      $(container).css("background-color", data.element.className);
      return data.text; 
     },
  });


});
 </script>
```